# Imageview is not refreshed android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-alertdialog

i want just clicking on the picture and one dialog box will come, in that dialog box there are several images i am just selecting that image and my image should be replaced by that image but my imageview goes blank and its not replacing the image

my code is below

```
   imgJuice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Resources resources = getResources();
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),
                    android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.choose_juice_image_dialog);

            ImageView imgJuiceOrange = (ImageView) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgJuiceOrange);
            imgJuiceOrange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    imgJuice.setImageDrawable(resources
                            .getDrawable(R.id.imgJuiceOrange));
     // also i have tried with setImageResource but nothing will be happen 

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    imgJuice.setImageDrawable(resources
        .getDrawable(R.drawable.imgJuiceOrange));
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

`imgJuiceOrange` is a `drawable` not an `id`.

Comment: sorry i forget that :(

Answer (score -1):

Also you forgot to add `dialog.show()` here :-

```
imgJuice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Resources resources = getResources();
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),
                    android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.choose_juice_image_dialog);

            ImageView imgJuiceOrange = (ImageView) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgJuiceOrange);
            imgJuiceOrange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    imgJuice.setImageDrawable(resources
                            .getDrawable(R.id.imgJuiceOrange));
     // also i have tried with setImageResource but nothing will be happen 

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            //Dialog Show code missing
            dialog.show();
        }
```